# SQL Server - Change Date Format

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date, datetime-format

I want to format my date column in SQL Server like this **Wed, 23** from given date format **4/23/2014**.

[image: Exactly like this in image below]

Is there any way to do this...?

SQL Server version is 2008

Comment: Leave presentation/formatting concerns in whatever application is actually performing the presentation. Within the database, these should be stored as `date` or `datetime2` columns - which don't **have** a format.

Comment: Please tell me is there any way to do formatting through SQL Server date functions. I must have to change the format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this

```
SELECT LEFT(DATENAME(dw, GETDATE()), 3) + ' , ' + CAST(Day(GetDate()) AS Varchar(10))
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/18011)**

Query would be like this

```
SELECT mydate,LEFT(DATENAME(dw, mydate), 3) + ' , ' + CAST(Day(mydate) AS Varchar(10)) As Date 
From tbl
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a56c2/2)

**O/P**

```
MYDATE        DATE
2014-04-21    Mon ,21
2014-04-22    Tue ,22
2014-04-23    Wed ,23
2014-04-24    Thu ,24
```

Comment: Oh Great, you're such a nice man. Thank you very much, and solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```
declare @a table(a date)
insert into @a values('4/21/2014'),('5/21/2014'),('6/21/2014')

select left(DATENAME(dw,a),3)+','+convert(varchar(10),datepart(day,a)) from @a
```

## [DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/18012)

Answer (score 1):

```
select Substring(DATENAME(WEEKDAY, getdate()), 0, 4)+' '+ DATENAME(dd, getdate())
```